# How to tackle SharePoint 2013 Custom Timer Job Posting Data To SIEBEL's SOAP Service Failed over the Intranet after Enabling TLS 1.2

Tags: soap, custom-timer-job, post, tls

The Custom Timer Job is deployed on the SharePoint 2013 (On-Premises) Farm.

The solution is written using the .NET Framework 4.5.

Timer Jobs are executed on the Windows Service Level so assuming nothing to do with IIS.

The Job sends the SharePoint's ListItems to the SIEBEL's SOAP Service.

It was working OK until the Network guys enable the TLS 1.2 over the Network.

The URL is accessible from browser with SSL.

We haven't updated the WSDL and Proxy class assuming that WSDL doesn't have to do anything with the TLS, please correct me if I am wrong.

We have tried the below from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)

1. Sebastian Castaldi's all three snippets.
2. Adding Remy's Code
3. Manuel Roldan Code

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788409/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error/32789483) somewhat help to change the behavior but not worked 
We do not have access to the Server, What we can do is to provide the WSP Solution to the Admin which generates log and using those we are getting below errors

**While Trying**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

### Log

### 1/14/2020 10:27:04 AM

Failed Using Ssl3
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

**While Trying**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

---

### 1/14/2020 10:27:04 AM

Failed Using Tls
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

**While Trying**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

### Log

### 1/14/2020 10:27:04 AM

Failed Using Tls11
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

**While Trying**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

### Log

### 1/14/2020 10:27:04 AM

Failed Using Tls12
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

We can see that when using the Tls12 the Error changes.

I think we have tried everything at the Application/Code level now need to check on the server level if we missed something please let me know.

We are able to Send the data by deleting below registry value:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS

[By Deleting PKCS registry we are able to POST the data to SIELBEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8RGz.png)

Also anyone please share any thoughts causing this error.